# FirebaseDatabase: Model is missing a constructor with no arguments

Tags: java, android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

So I've added Firebase data like this:
[image: Database]

and I called the data inside a ListView:

```
private void displayStudentChatMessages() {
    listofMessages = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.list_msg);
    DatabaseReference ref = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference(String.valueOf(generateChatID));

    adapter = new FirebaseListAdapter<StudentMessageModel>(this, StudentMessageModel.class, R.layout.item_chat_right, ref) {
        @Override
        protected void populateView(View v, StudentMessageModel model, int position) {
            TextView messageUsername = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.message_user_sender);
            TextView messageText = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.message_user);
            TextView messageTime = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.message_usertime);

            messageUsername.setText(model.getStudentName());
            messageText.setText(model.getStudentMessage());
            messageTime.setText(DateFormat.format("yyyy-MM-dd (HH:mm:ss)", model.getStudentTime()));
        }
    };

    listofMessages.setAdapter(adapter);
    listofMessages.setTranscriptMode(ListView.TRANSCRIPT_MODE_ALWAYS_SCROLL);
}
```

But I got the error:

> com.google.firebase.database.DatabaseException: Class com.androidports.autosiskola.StudentMessageModel is missing a constructor with no arguments

I need those data where the root's child is the generated-name (*test-testteacher-student-teacher*).

Here is how I added the constructor:

```
public class StudentMessageModel {

private String studentUsername;
private String studentName;
private String studentMessage;
private String generatedChatID;
private long studentTime;

public StudentMessageModel(String studentUsername, String studentName, String studentMessage, String generatedChatID) {
    this.studentUsername = studentUsername;
    this.studentName = studentName;
    this.studentMessage = studentMessage;
    this.generatedChatID = generatedChatID;

    studentTime = new Date().getTime();
}
```

and getters and setters.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I believe the error is self-explanatory. You must have a constructor with no arguments. Like this:

```
public class StudentMessageModel {

private String studentUsername;
private String studentName;
private String studentMessage;
private String generatedChatID;
private long studentTime;

public StudentMessageModel(String studentUsername, String studentName, String studentMessage, String generatedChatID) {
    this.studentUsername = studentUsername;
    this.studentName = studentName;
    this.studentMessage = studentMessage;
    this.generatedChatID = generatedChatID;

    studentTime = new Date().getTime();
}

public StudentMessageModel(){}
```

Comment: If I add public StudentMessageModel(){} to my Model I got:
`java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'void android.widget.TextView.setText(java.lang.CharSequence)' on a null object reference`

Comment: Looks like Android can't find a TextView with the ID `message_user_sender` in your `item_chat_right.xml` . Please make sure it exists

Comment: **item_chat_right.xml**:
`<TextView
            android:id="@+id/message_user_sender"
...`
I think my main problem isn't the model, more likely this line: `DatabaseReference ref = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference(String.valueOf(generateChatID));`

Comment: Try replacing it with `DatabaseReference ref = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference("test-testteacher-student-teacher");`

Comment: Same error. Btw. `String.valueOf(generatedChatID));` is the same as `test-testteacher-student-teacher"` at the moment.

Comment: The answers from Rosario and Frank are correct for resolving the error in your question. The `NullPointerException` is a separate error which looks to be caused be using `findViewById(R.id.message....)` (which is looking in the activity or fragment layout. Change them to `v.findViewById`, which will look in the list item's layout.

Comment: You were right. The reference was good, but somehow I pushed null data inside the Firebase database (the formatString looked like: `String formatStudentname=""+studentfirstname+" "+studentlastname;`
+ I need that empty constructor

Answer (score 2):

As the error message says, you must have a public constructor without arguments. This is used when re-creating your object from the database.

In addition you must either mark your fields as public, or provide getters and setters for them. That way Firebase knows what fields to populate from the JSON properties in the database.

So:

```
public class StudentMessageModel {

    public String studentUsername;
    public String studentName;
    public String studentMessage;
    public String generatedChatID;
    public long studentTime;

    public StudentMessageModel(String studentUsername, String studentName, String studentMessage, String generatedChatID) {
        this.studentUsername = studentUsername;
        this.studentName = studentName;
        this.studentMessage = studentMessage;
        this.generatedChatID = generatedChatID;

        studentTime = new Date().getTime();
    }
    public StudentMessageModel() {
        // public default constructor, which Firebase uses
    }
```

Comment: If I add the public constructor without arguments I got the error under the comment of @Rosário Pereira Fernandes. item_chat_right.xml exists, Textviews are exists. I've followed a more simple example where the constructor values were private as well and it's working. I think `DatabaseReference ref = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference("test-testteache‌​r-student-teacher");` is the problem.

Comment: In my code I also marked the fields as `public`, which is a second necessary step. If that still doesn't work, update your question with the **latest** [minimal code that reproduces the problem](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Comment: I think I fixed it, I just saw that I pushed a null value inside my DB. `Private` is enough with `public` getters and setters and constructor + default constructor.